# Problems when connect API from iOS App

Tags: ios, asp.net, api

I'm developing some APIs for a web service using `asp.net` api 2.0. I've deployed a server and tested these APIs in Postman. It works well. However when my iOS team connect APIs, they receive this error:

```
"handleErrorNetwork: Error Domain=/nameApi/abc Code=-1011 "Request failed: internal server error (500)" UserInfo={com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7fc5779f1b00> { URL: http://myAPIlink } { status code: 500, headers {
    "Cache-Control" = "no-cache";
    "Content-Length" = 56;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Tue, 17 Nov 2015 09:38:26 GMT";
    Expires = "-1";
    Pragma = "no-cache";
    Server = "Microsoft-IIS/7.5";
    "X-AspNet-Version" = "4.0.30319";
    "X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET"; } }, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://myAPIlink, com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data=<7b227374 61747573 223a322c 226d6573 73616765 223a2254 68652067 6976656e 20686561 64657220 77617320 6e6f7420 666f756e 642e227d>, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: internal server error (500)}
```

Does anyone known if this problem is client or server issue and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error **500** means **Internal Server Error**. There is something wrong on the server side. To troubleshoot the cause have to look into the logs on the server side.

Comment: If server side has error, why I can connect it from Postman @Rafal Sroka. Can you explain it ? :)

Comment: Well, the error code `500` is sent in the response returned by the server, not produced in the app. Might be that the app is sending something funny that is causing this. Server however, should be discarding requests that it doesn't understand, returning error code 400 (request malformed) instead of indicating Internal Server Error. That's why I recommend looking into the logs to find out what might be wrong with the request or server's handling of it.

Comment: Ok, I will try it. Thanks for your solution :)

Answer (score 0):

When I decoded your error data it printed this:

```
{"status":2,"message":"The given header was not found."}
```

---

Also, as a side note you can use `AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseDataErrorKey` to get from error.userInfo the raw `NSData` and convert that to a human-readable string with like this:

```
var datastring = NSString(data: NSData!, encoding: UInt)
```